# How to define a version of createSelector typed for my app?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings, redux-toolkit, reselect

In redux-toolkit docs they suggest you to create the following definition to have proper types when you use useSelector hook:

```
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

This will save you of having to type all the selectors with the root state.

However, when it's time to define memoized selector with `createSelector` there are no instructions about how to do a similar thing.
Is there any shortcut for this or I have to manually type every memoized selector?

Comment: What's the error? What do you expect?

Comment: Who says there is an error? I want to create a typed version of createSelector just like in the example I posted, where there is a version of useSelector hook typed for my specific app

Comment: Have you found solution to this?

Comment: no, not yet. If you do, please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on a app that I wanted to do the same. For my needs, I just wanted a simple selector, so I did this:

```ts
// store.ts

// …omitted store configuration

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

// create a generic type called AppSelector
export type AppSelector<Return> = (state: RootState) => Return
// create a custom `createSelector` that uses the type above
export const createAppSelector = <R>(selector: AppSelector<R>): AppSelector<R> => selector
```

With the types above, we can do the following:

```
const selectTitle: AppSelector<string> = (state) => state.title;
// Note that using the AppSelector type requires you to always pass the return type argument
// It's much easier to use the createAppSelector function
// selectTitle and selectTitle2 accomplish the same thing
const selectTitle2 = createAppSelector((state) => state.title);
```

When inside `createAppSelector`, `state` will correctly have the `RootState` type.

The limitation of this form is that, unlike `createSelector`, `createAppSelector` only allows you to create a single selector and doesn't allow you to combine or mutate the selections.

Hopefully someday we'll have a way to `const createAppSelector: TypedCreateSelector<RootState> = createSelector;`

Comment: That looks neat. But why not just an alias rather an actual function?  like this `export const createAppSelector: <R>(selector: AppSelector<R>) => AppSelector<R> = createSelector;`

Comment: The way `createSelector` is typed doesn't allow it to be an alias, unfortunately. If you try to alias it, you'll get an error saying that `createSelector` is not assignable to type `<R>(selector: AppSelector<R>) => AppSelector<R>`, due to all the overloads that `createSelector` has.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is years old now at this point but just in case anybody else comes across this. This is what I came up with:

```
export type TypedCreateSelector<State> = <
  SelectorsArray extends readonly Selector<State>[],
  Result,
>(
  ...args: Parameters<typeof createSelector<SelectorsArray, Result>>
) => ReturnType<typeof createSelector<SelectorsArray, Result>>;
```

So now You can have something like this:

```
export const createAppSelector: TypedCreateSelector<RootState> = createSelector;
export const createDraftSafeAppSelector: TypedCreateSelector<RootState> =
  createDraftSafeSelector;
```

Which is similar to the way Redux-Toolkit wants you to create typed versions of the hooks and reuse them throughout your project.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Reselect v5.1.0 now provides [`createSelector.withTypes<RootState>()`](https://reselect.js.org/api/createSelector#defining-a-pre-typed-createselector) which allows you to easily create a "pre-typed" version of `createSelector`:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

export interface RootState {
  todos: { id: number; completed: boolean }[]
  alerts: { id: number; read: boolean }[]
}

export const createAppSelector = createSelector.withTypes<RootState>()

const selectTodoIds = createAppSelector(
  [
    // Type of `state` is set to `RootState`, no need to manually set the type
    state => state.todos
  ],
  todos => todos.map(({ id }) => id)
)
```